# How do i run a db select and get the result in iex?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

In elixir iex, I want to know the basic steps.

1.If i had the module and How to import it.

2.I want run `from l in '' where` and get the map.

Im tried to import with `import Ecto.Query`, and then
I was running some like `from l in '' where`, i got this 
`#Ecto.Query<from l in "", where: >`, how to get the data result?

Comment: You should really add an answer to your question instead of editing the question itself with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Ecto.Query
alias Repo
Repo.one(from s in Struct)
```

Maybe also look at [`all`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:all/2)